# read event trigger on image downloading from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I use amazon services. I have a task to track an IP address and user agent for each who download an image from s3.
I use amazon API gateway and amazon lambda and Amazon S3. Is it possible? I found triggers only on uploading or deleting the file from s3

Comment: What do you mean by "run a lambda function on image downloading from s3"? Can you describe your desired process in more detail? (Please edit your question rather than putting it in a comment.)

Comment: I mean read event trigger

Comment: There is no concept of a "read trigger". Please describe what you would like to happen. For example, what does somebody do, what would you like it to trigger, what would that thing then do. Basically, _WHY_ do you want to trigger on a Read?

Comment: I want to track an IP address and user agent for each request of an image from s3.

Comment: What do you wish to _do_ with this information? Is it just for logging, or do you need to respond to it in real-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As at now, S3 doesn't have object read event trigger. What you may do is to use cloudtrail to track the api call to read object of the s3 bucket and create an alarm to trigger a lambda function.

ex: S3 -> CloudTrail -> CloudWatch Event -> Rule -> Lamdba

Another simple solution would be to allow the object download directly via lambda.

ex: API Gateway -> Lambda -> S3

This will return the lambda output which can be the blob (be aware of the size limit) or preferably pre-signed url for the object.

Comment: CW Alarm or CW Event?

Comment: Well, a rule to capture the event. Answer corrected

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your goal is "I want to track an IP address and user agent for each request of an image from s3".

To obtain this information, you should activate [Amazon S3 server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html):

> Server access logging provides detailed records for the requests that are made to a bucket.

The [Amazon S3 Server Access Log Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html) includes IP address, User Agent and other standard web log information:

```
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be awsexamplebucket1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 3E57427F3EXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /awsexamplebucket1?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 7 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - s9lzHYrFp76ZVxRcpX9+5cjAnEH2ROuNkd2BHfIa6UkFVdtjf5mKR3/eTPFvsiP/XV/VLi31234= SigV2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader awsexamplebucket1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.1
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be awsexamplebucket1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 891CE47D2EXAMPLE REST.GET.LOGGING_STATUS - "GET /awsexamplebucket1?logging HTTP/1.1" 200 - 242 - 11 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - 9vKBE6vMhrNiWHZmb2L0mXOcqPGzQOI5XLnCtZNPxev+Hf+7tpT6sxDwDty4LHBUOZJG96N1234= SigV2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader awsexamplebucket1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.1
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be awsexamplebucket1 [06/Feb/2019:00:00:38 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be A1206F460EXAMPLE REST.GET.BUCKETPOLICY - "GET /awsexamplebucket1?policy HTTP/1.1" 404 NoSuchBucketPolicy 297 - 38 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - BNaBsXZQQDbssi6xMBdBU2sLt+Yf5kZDmeBUP35sFoKa3sLLeMC78iwEIWxs99CRUrbS4n11234= SigV2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader awsexamplebucket1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.1
79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be awsexamplebucket1 [06/Feb/2019:00:01:00 +0000] 192.0.2.3 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be 7B4A0FABBEXAMPLE REST.GET.VERSIONING - "GET /awsexamplebucket1?versioning HTTP/1.1" 200 - 113 - 33 - "-" "S3Console/0.4" - Ke1bUcazaN1jWuUlPJaxF64cQVpUEhoZKEG/hmy/gijN/I1DeWqDfFvnpybfEseEME/u7ME1234= SigV2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader awsexamplebucket1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com TLSV1.1
```